# Ruby Counting The Number of Unique Chars in a String

Tags: ruby

I am working with a string of chars `alphabet ="AABBBCCCCDDDDDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZZZZZZ"` I want to create a def that counts the number of unique chars in a string and the percentage of unique chars without having to use `alphabet.count("A"), alphabet.count"("B"), alphabet.count("C"), etc etc` so I don't have to waste time tediously entering each char into the `.count()` method.

I have succeeded in one sense, that I get the output I wanted, but the output repeats each result numerous times due to how I structured my `for` loop

Here is my code:

```
alphabet ="AABBBCCCCDDDDDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZZZZZZ"

def count_num_of_uniq_chars(string)
  len = string.length
  len = len.to_f
  for i in 0..len-1

    uniq_char=string[i]
    puts "uniq_chars --> #{uniq_char}"

    count_of_uniq_char = string.count(string[i])

    puts "count_of_uniq_char--> #{count_of_uniq_char}"


    percent_of_uniq_char = ( (count_of_uniq_char / len) * 100 )
    percent_of_uniq_char=percent_of_uniq_char.to_f

    puts "there are #{count_of_uniq_char} letter '#{uniq_char}'s in the string which is #{percent_of_uniq_char}% of strings length "
    puts
  end # loop end

end #def end

count_num_of_uniq_chars(alphabet)
```

Outputs as:

```
uniq_chars --> A
count_of_uniq_char--> 2
there are 2 letter 'A's in the string which is 4.878048780487805% of strings length

uniq_chars --> A
count_of_uniq_char--> 2
there are 2 letter 'A's in the string which is 4.878048780487805% of strings length

uniq_chars --> B
count_of_uniq_char--> 3
there are 3 letter 'B's in the string which is 7.317073170731707% of strings length

uniq_chars --> B
count_of_uniq_char--> 3
there are 3 letter 'B's in the string which is 7.317073170731707% of strings length

uniq_chars --> B
count_of_uniq_char--> 3
there are 3 letter 'B's in the string which is 7.317073170731707% of strings length

uniq_chars --> C
count_of_uniq_char--> 4
there are 4 letter 'C's in the string which is 9.75609756097561% of strings length

uniq_chars --> C
count_of_uniq_char--> 4
there are 4 letter 'C's in the string which is 9.75609756097561% of strings length

uniq_chars --> C
count_of_uniq_char--> 4
there are 4 letter 'C's in the string which is 9.75609756097561% of strings length

uniq_chars --> C
count_of_uniq_char--> 4
there are 4 letter 'C's in the string which is 9.75609756097561% of strings length

uniq_chars --> D
count_of_uniq_char--> 5
there are 5 letter 'D's in the string which is 12.195121951219512% of strings length

uniq_chars --> D
count_of_uniq_char--> 5
there are 5 letter 'D's in the string which is 12.195121951219512% of strings length

uniq_chars --> D
count_of_uniq_char--> 5
there are 5 letter 'D's in the string which is 12.195121951219512% of strings length

uniq_chars --> D
count_of_uniq_char--> 5
there are 5 letter 'D's in the string which is 12.195121951219512% of strings length

uniq_chars --> D
count_of_uniq_char--> 5
there are 5 letter 'D's in the string which is 12.195121951219512% of strings length

uniq_chars --> E
count_of_uniq_char--> 1
there are 1 letter 'E's in the string which is 2.4390243902439024% of strings length

uniq_chars --> F
count_of_uniq_char--> 1
there are 1 letter 'F's in the string which is 2.4390243902439024% of strings length

uniq_chars --> G
count_of_uniq_char--> 1
there are 1 letter 'G's in the string which is 2.4390243902439024% of strings length

uniq_chars --> H
count_of_uniq_char--> 1
there are 1 letter 'H's in the string which is 2.4390243902439024% of strings length

uniq_chars --> I
count_of_uniq_char--> 1
there are 1 letter 'I's in the string which is 2.4390243902439024% of strings length

uniq_chars --> J
count_of_uniq_char--> 1
there are 1 letter 'J's in the string which is 2.4390243902439024% of strings length

uniq_chars --> K
count_of_uniq_char--> 1
there are 1 letter 'K's in the string which is 2.4390243902439024% of strings length

uniq_chars --> L
count_of_uniq_char--> 1
there are 1 letter 'L's in the string which is 2.4390243902439024% of strings length

uniq_chars --> M
count_of_uniq_char--> 1
there are 1 letter 'M's in the string which is 2.4390243902439024% of strings length

uniq_chars --> N
count_of_uniq_char--> 1
there are 1 letter 'N's in the string which is 2.4390243902439024% of strings length

uniq_chars --> O
count_of_uniq_char--> 1
there are 1 letter 'O's in the string which is 2.4390243902439024% of strings length

uniq_chars --> P
count_of_uniq_char--> 1
there are 1 letter 'P's in the string which is 2.4390243902439024% of strings length

uniq_chars --> Q
count_of_uniq_char--> 1
there are 1 letter 'Q's in the string which is 2.4390243902439024% of strings length

uniq_chars --> R
count_of_uniq_char--> 1
there are 1 letter 'R's in the string which is 2.4390243902439024% of strings length

uniq_chars --> S
count_of_uniq_char--> 1
there are 1 letter 'S's in the string which is 2.4390243902439024% of strings length

uniq_chars --> T
count_of_uniq_char--> 1
there are 1 letter 'T's in the string which is 2.4390243902439024% of strings length

uniq_chars --> U
count_of_uniq_char--> 1
there are 1 letter 'U's in the string which is 2.4390243902439024% of strings length

uniq_chars --> V
count_of_uniq_char--> 1
there are 1 letter 'V's in the string which is 2.4390243902439024% of strings length

uniq_chars --> W
count_of_uniq_char--> 1
there are 1 letter 'W's in the string which is 2.4390243902439024% of strings length

uniq_chars --> X
count_of_uniq_char--> 1
there are 1 letter 'X's in the string which is 2.4390243902439024% of strings length

uniq_chars --> Y
count_of_uniq_char--> 1
there are 1 letter 'Y's in the string which is 2.4390243902439024% of strings length

uniq_chars --> Z
count_of_uniq_char--> 6
there are 6 letter 'Z's in the string which is 14.634146341463413% of strings length

uniq_chars --> Z
count_of_uniq_char--> 6
there are 6 letter 'Z's in the string which is 14.634146341463413% of strings length

uniq_chars --> Z
count_of_uniq_char--> 6
there are 6 letter 'Z's in the string which is 14.634146341463413% of strings length

uniq_chars --> Z
count_of_uniq_char--> 6
there are 6 letter 'Z's in the string which is 14.634146341463413% of strings length

uniq_chars --> Z
count_of_uniq_char--> 6
there are 6 letter 'Z's in the string which is 14.634146341463413% of strings length

uniq_chars --> Z
count_of_uniq_char--> 6
there are 6 letter 'Z's in the string which is 14.634146341463413% of strings length
```

Notice the output statement per letter repeats based upon how many times that letter occurs in the string. How can I get it to output once per letter regardless of how many occurrences are in the string?

Comment: Using [String#count](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-count) is highly inefficient, as it requires each character in the string to be examined for each unique character. You should be using a method that makes a single pass through the string.

Answer (score 5):

> I want to create a def that counts the number of unique chars in a string [...]

You can get the string's chars via [`String#each_char`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-each_char) and have [`Enumerable#tally`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally) count the occurrences: (`tally` requires Ruby 2.7)

```
alphabet.each_char.tally
#=> {
#     "A"=>2, "B"=>3, "C"=>4, "D"=>5, "E"=>1, "F"=>1, "G"=>1,
#     "H"=>1, "I"=>1, "J"=>1, "K"=>1, "L"=>1, "M"=>1, "N"=>1,
#     "O"=>1, "P"=>1, "Q"=>1, "R"=>1, "S"=>1, "T"=>1, "U"=>1,
#     "V"=>1, "W"=>1, "X"=>1, "Y"=>1, "Z"=>6
#   }
```

To get the percentages, you simply divide the char's occurrences by the total number of chars, e.g.:

```
hash = alphabet.each_char.tally
hash.each do |char, count|
  q = count.quo(hash.size)
  puts format(" %s | %d | %4.1f%%", char, count, q * 100)
end
```

Output:

```
 A | 2 |  7.7%
 B | 3 | 11.5%
 C | 4 | 15.4%
 D | 5 | 19.2%
 E | 1 |  3.8%
 F | 1 |  3.8%
 G | 1 |  3.8%
 H | 1 |  3.8%
 I | 1 |  3.8%
 J | 1 |  3.8%
 K | 1 |  3.8%
 L | 1 |  3.8%
 M | 1 |  3.8%
 N | 1 |  3.8%
 O | 1 |  3.8%
 P | 1 |  3.8%
 Q | 1 |  3.8%
 R | 1 |  3.8%
 S | 1 |  3.8%
 T | 1 |  3.8%
 U | 1 |  3.8%
 V | 1 |  3.8%
 W | 1 |  3.8%
 X | 1 |  3.8%
 Y | 1 |  3.8%
 Z | 6 | 23.1%
```

Instead of `hash.size` (number of unique chars) you could also divide by `alphabet.size` (number of chars in the string), depending on what you want.

Answer (score 4):

Here are three ways to do that.

```
alphabet = "AABBBCCCCDDDDDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZZZZZZ"
```

**Use the method [Enumerable#tally](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally), which made its debut in Ruby 2.7.0**

```
h = alphabet.each_char.tally
  #=> {"A"=>2, "B"=>3, "C"=>4,..., "Z"=>6}
```

**Use the form of the class method [Hash::new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60071322/ruby-counting-the-number-of-unique-chars-in-a-string) that takes an argument of zero (but no block), the argument being the hash's *default value***

```
h = alphabet.each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |c,h| h[c] += 1 }
  #=> {"A"=>2, "B"=>3, "C"=>4,..., "Z"=>6}
```

`h[c] += 1` expands to `h[c] = h[c] + 1`. If `h` does not have a key `c`, `h[c]` on the right of the equality returns the default value of zero, yielding `h[c] = 0 + 1`.

**Use the method [Enumerable#group_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)**

```
h = alphabet.each_char.
             group_by(&:itself).
             transform_values(&:count)
  #=> <same as above>
```

See [Hash#transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values).

The steps are as follows:

```
enum = alphabet.each_char
  #=> #<Enumerator: "AABBB...ZZZ":each_char> 
a = enum.group_by(&:itself)
  #=> {"A"=>["A", "A"], "B"=>["B", "B", "B"],...,
  #          "Z"=>["Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z"]} 
a.transform_values(&:count)
  #=> {"A"=>2, "B"=>3,..., "Z"=>6}
```

**Using the hash**

Once you have the hash you can display information as you wish. For example:

```
n = alphabet.size
  #=> 41  
h.each { |k,v| puts "#{v} #{k}'s #{(100*v.fdiv(n)).round(2)}%" }
2 A's 4.88%
3 B's 7.32%
4 C's 9.76%
...
1 X's 2.44%
1 Y's 2.44%
6 Z's 14.63%
```

Comment: marvellous solution. I learned a lot from your approach regarding  hashes and iterators in ruby

Comment: lbdl, I'm pleased to be of help. I made a small change to my answer, adding a third approach that uses `Enumerable#tally`, a method that may not have existed at the time the question was asked.

Comment: yes I saw the tally answer, Im using an older version at present but good to know, Im just starting out with Ruby, Im very pleased with it so far

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string.chars.uniq` and get rid of `len`, the for loop and the `uniq_char` initialization:

```
def count_num_of_uniq_chars(string)
  string.chars.uniq.each do |uniq_char|
    puts "uniq_chars --> #{uniq_char}"

    count_of_uniq_char = string.count(uniq_char)

    puts "count_of_uniq_char--> #{count_of_uniq_char}"


    percent_of_uniq_char = ( (count_of_uniq_char / string.length.to_f) * 100 )
    percent_of_uniq_char=percent_of_uniq_char.to_f

    puts "there are #{count_of_uniq_char} letter '#{uniq_char}'s in the string which is #{percent_of_uniq_char}% of strings length \n\n"
  end
end
```

See [`String#chars`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/String.html#method-i-chars) and [`Array#uniq`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Array.html#method-i-uniq).

Notice the `percent_of_uniq_char` is calculated as the `count_of_uniq_char` divided the length of the string converted to float. If that's a problem for this case,  you can initialize it outside the loop.

Comment: Counting elements by calling `count` for each element is very inefficient because the entire collection has to be traversed each time.

Comment: That part of the code is in the question which OP provided. I didn't focus on anything else more than in the question _How can I get it to output once per letter regardless of how many occurrences are in the string?_ Didn't think either in giving a fast-as-hell improved version of the code as it might be that he/she is playing around with the language to know more about it, nor I can.

Comment: Well, I did, I proposed to use `each` instead of `for`. But, who wouldn't?

Comment: No offense. I just wanted to point out a shortcoming that was very obvious to me.

Comment: Of course no offense at all @Stefan. Personally, I gratefully take everybody's comments as a way to improve the code and as advice for future scenarios, so, thanks for this one.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done like this

```
def count_occ(str)
    d=Hash.new(0)
    str.split('').each do |ch|
            d[ch]=d[ch]+1
    end
    d.each do |key,value|
        count_ch=value
        percentage=count_ch/Float(str.length)
        puts "there are #{count_ch} letter '#{key}'s in the string which is #{percentage}% of strings length "
    end

end
```